# Equivalent of \iffieldundef under \DeclareSourcemap command

Tags: biblatex, biber

I use `\DeclareSourcemap` command to fix a whole bunch of things that get rendered in an undesirable manner. For instance, I use it to suppress the month of publication if an article has been published in an academic journal and has volume information:

```
\DeclareSourcemap{  
    \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
        \map{
            \pertype{article}
            \step[fieldsource=volume,final]
            \step[fieldset=month,null]
            \step[fieldset=month_numeric,null]
        }                   
    }
}
```

What I don't know is how to make the substitution conditional to absence of a field. For instance I don't want the `Url`s that don't come with a `Urldate` to show up. The syntax I am searching for would have a logic similar to this:

```
\DeclareSourcemap{  
    \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
        \map{
            \iffieldundef{urldate}
            \step[fieldset=url,null]
        }                   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try the new `notfield` mapping function with biber 2.6 DEV and biblatex 3.5 DEV:

```
\DeclareSourcemap{  
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
      \map{
        \step[notfield=urldate, final]
        \step[fieldset=url, null]
      }                   
   }
}
```

or, if you don't need to do anything much after the test:

```
\DeclareSourcemap{  
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
      \map{
        \step[notfield=urldate, fieldset=url, null]
      }                   
   }
}
```

Comment: Does this solution work for you? For some reason it doesn't work here. Keep in mind that those urldata fields are not necessarily blank. They are non-existent.

Comment: Actually you are right. I will add some suitable functionality to biber 2.6 dev soon and update here.

Comment: Thanks Philip! This actually works. The only issue is that the changes break compatibility with some stuff I already use. My environment definition and the outputs are (here)[https://gist.github.com/retrography/6000b184aee4bb0e6c06201ff7e0f3ac]. Not sure why this happens.

Comment: Hmm, can you open a ticket on the Github biber tracker:  https://github.com/plk/biber/issues with a minimal example of what's broken?